# Comunicação TCP/IP usando Socket

Tags: java, socket

Preciso fazer um trabalho da faculdade, onde é necessário fazer uma comunicação TCP/IP algo como um "chat de bate-papo" é o que tenho em mente para fazer.
Mas surgiram algumas dúvidas, não sei exatamente como perguntá-las então fiz um desenho de duas maneiras que eu acho que deve ser a arquitetura desse tipo de comunicação. Estou utilizando a linguagem `Java` para o programa, mas resolvi não especificar a linguagem no Título para que caso alguém de outra linguagem tenha a mesma dúvida possa sanar com o exemplos daqui mesmo. Porém se puderem responder em `Java`eu agradeço demais.

### Primeira arquitetura que tenho dúvida

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Se essa arquitetura estiver correta, então eu precisarei abrir uma Thread para cada conexão Privada que a `app1` for fazer?
Por exemplo: A `app1` se comunica com a `app2` com a `porta 99998` e se caso for conversar com a `app3` precisará fazer uma `Thread` e se comunicar com a `app3`através da `porta 99997`?

### Segunda arquitetura que tenho dúvida

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Nessa arquitetura todas as mensagens passarão pelo `Servidor Central` e ele será encarregado de enviar a mensagem para determinada aplicação.
Se essa for a arquitetura correta, como posso fazer para o `app1`conversar com o `app2`? Eu sei que vai passar pelo `Servidor Central`mas como ele vai saber que aquela mensagem do `app1`vai para o `app2`e não para outro? 
E como farei pra enviar a mensagem que já está no `Servidor Central`para a `app`escolhido pelo `app1`?

As dúvidas são essas, espero que estejam claras, se não estiverem por favor peço que me alertem para que eu possa corrigir e deixar mais o mais claro possível.

Talvez o código que eu fiz possa ajudar em alguma coisa, não sei como mas vou publicá-lo, está de uma forma bem ruim pois não conheço totalmente os métodos e ainda não formulei uma boa maneira de fazer uma melhor comunicação.

### ClienteUm

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
//import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClienteUm {

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.3", 12345);

            DataOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader leitorBuffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            escreverMensagemAoServidor(fluxoSaidaDados, leitorBuffered);
            lerMensagemServidor();

        } catch (IOException iec) {
            System.out.println(iec.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void escreverMensagemAoServidor(final DataOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados, final BufferedReader leitorBuffered)

            throws IOException {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String mensagemSaida;
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        mensagemSaida = leitorBuffered.readLine();
                        fluxoSaidaDados.writeUTF("Mensagem do Cliente (1): " + mensagemSaida + "=127.0.0.2");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
    private static void lerMensagemServidor() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    DataInputStream fluxoEntradaDados = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    while(true){

                        String mensagemOutroClienteQueVeioPeloServidor = fluxoEntradaDados.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(mensagemOutroClienteQueVeioPeloServidor);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

### Servidor Central

Ele está sendo chamado no código de `ServidorUm` pois já era um código que estava testando antes.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;

public class ServidorUm {

    private static ServerSocket servidorSocket;
    private static List<Socket> socketsConectados;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            servidorSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
            socketsConectados = new ArrayList<Socket>();
            do {
                Socket socket = servidorSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream fluxoEntradaDados = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("Cliente "+ socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress() +" se conectou! ");
                socketsConectados.add(socket);
                lerMensagemDoCliente(fluxoEntradaDados);

            } while (true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ops! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void lerMensagemDoCliente(final DataInputStream fluxoEntradaDados) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String mensagemEntrada = "";

                try {
                    while (true) {
                        mensagemEntrada = fluxoEntradaDados.readUTF();
                        String[] teste = mensagemEntrada.split("=");
                        String mensagem = teste[0];
                        String paraQuemEnviar = teste[1];
                        System.out.println("\n" + mensagem);

                        Socket socketQueReceberaMensagem = socketsConectados.stream()
                        .filter(x -> x.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress().equals(paraQuemEnviar))
                        .findFirst().get();

                        DataOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados = new DataOutputStream(socketQueReceberaMensagem.getOutputStream());
                        fluxoSaidaDados.writeUTF(mensagem);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

### ClienteDois ##

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
//import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClienteDois {

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.2", 12345);

            DataOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader leitorBuffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            escreverMensagemAoServidor(fluxoSaidaDados, leitorBuffered);
            lerMensagemServidor();

        } catch (IOException iec) {
            System.out.println(iec.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void lerMensagemServidor() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    DataInputStream fluxoEntradaDados = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    while(true){

                        String mensagemOutroClienteQueVeioPeloServidor = fluxoEntradaDados.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(mensagemOutroClienteQueVeioPeloServidor);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private static void escreverMensagemAoServidor(final DataOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados, final BufferedReader leitorBuffered)
            throws IOException {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String mensagemSaida;
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        mensagemSaida = leitorBuffered.readLine();
                        fluxoSaidaDados.writeUTF("Mensagem do Cliente (2): " + mensagemSaida + "=127.0.0.3");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Bom Articuno... Eu não consigo iniciar uma implementação de alguma coisa sem antes saber como ela funciona... Então, se minha pergunta é a respeito de como funciona a comunicação, como posso ter algo implementado? Não tenho nada feito infelizmente, a única coisa que posso fazer é editar a pergunta e retirar o "Estou fazendo" para "Desejo iniciar um trabalho da faculdade", dessa forma te ajuda?

Comment: Sua pergunta pode ser considerada ampla demais e ser fechada, por isso eu dei a dica de adicionar o codigo, afinal podem existir N jeitos de fazer isso, o que faz a duvida deixar de ser especifica e ser ampla demais.

Comment: Por isso mesmo que eu mandei duas pequenas imagens perguntando se alguma das duas maneiras estão corretas, se não estão corretas, então simplesmente cabe a quem vai responder (se quiser) enviar outra solução, estou certo ou errado?

Comment: Ok, só tentei ajudar alertando sobre o fechamento(e ja tem 2 votos pra fechar essa pergunta como ampla). Ai vai da sua escolha aplicar minhas dicas ou nao, mas se nao concorda, é direito seu mesmo.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas igual eu disse acima, como vou mandar algo implementado, se não tenho algo implementado por não saber como iniciar essa implementação, concorda?

Comment: Ponto de partida: https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-sockets-criando-comunicacoes-em-java/9465 Ps.: Não acho que utilizar portas seja viável para identificar o remetente e destinatário.

Comment: Obrigado Valdeir Psr

Comment: Adicionei o código, espero que fique mais fácil agora, desculpa pela falta de boas práticas e as "gambiarras" foram as maneiras que encontrei de fazê-los se comunicarem tendo pouca experiência com esse tipo de aplicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez minha dúvida não tenha ficado tão clara, mas eu só gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de se fazer uma comunicação `TCP/IP`, algo como um `(CHAT de BATE-PAPO)`, existem várias formas de se fazer uma comunicação `TCP/IP`, mas entre as duas do desenho que enviei na pergunta, a melhor é uma estrutura que use um `SERVIDOR CENTRAL`como intermediador das informações passadas por cada aplicação conectada a ela.

Então para fechar a pergunta, vou adicionar meu código com essa comunicação feita, foi a melhor maneira que encontrei.

### SERVIDOR CENTRAL

O `Servidor Central`nesse tipo de estrutura ele serve para encaminhar as mensagens que chegam à ele para um outro usuário que foi solicitado.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServidorCentral {

    private static ServerSocket socketServidorCentral;
    private static List<Socket> socketsConectados;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            socketServidorCentral = new ServerSocket(12345);
            socketsConectados = new ArrayList<Socket>();
            do {
                Socket socket = socketServidorCentral.accept();
                ObjectInputStream fluxoEntradaDados = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("Cliente " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress() + " se conectou! ");
                socketsConectados.add(socket);
                lerMensagemDoCliente(fluxoEntradaDados);

            } while (true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ops! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void lerMensagemDoCliente(final ObjectInputStream fluxoEntradaDados) {
        new Thread() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void run() {
                String mensagemEntrada = "";

                try {
                    while (true) {

                        Socket socketQueReceberaMensagem = null; // socketsConectados.stream()
                        // .filter(x ->
                        // x.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress().equals(paraQuemEnviar))
                        // .findFirst().get();

                        DadoCompartilhado dadoCompartilhado = (DadoCompartilhado) fluxoEntradaDados.readObject();

                        for (Socket socketConectado : socketsConectados) {
                            if (socketConectado.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress()
                                    .equals(dadoCompartilhado.getEmailEntrega())) {
                                socketQueReceberaMensagem = socketConectado;
                            }
                        }

                        ObjectOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados = new ObjectOutputStream(socketQueReceberaMensagem.getOutputStream());
                        fluxoSaidaDados.writeObject(dadoCompartilhado);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

### Cliente Um

Essa classe vai simular uma aplicação qualquer que irá se conectar ao `Servidor Central`, ela atualmente apenas envia mensagens a outro cliente e caso escreva `Enviar` ela enviará um arquivo, mas é preciso setar o caminho do arquivo na mão.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClienteUm {

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.3", 12345);

            ObjectOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader leitorBuffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            escreverMensagemAoServidor(fluxoSaidaDados, leitorBuffered);
            lerMensagemServidor();

        } catch (IOException iec) {
            System.out.println(iec.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void escreverMensagemAoServidor(final ObjectOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados,
            final BufferedReader leitorBuffered)

            throws IOException {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String mensagemSaida;
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        mensagemSaida = leitorBuffered.readLine();
                        DadoCompartilhado dadoCompartilhado = new DadoCompartilhado();
                        dadoCompartilhado.setEmailEntrega("127.0.0.2");
                        dadoCompartilhado.setMensagem("Mensagem do Cliente (1): " + mensagemSaida);

                        if (mensagemSaida.equals("Enviar")){
                            dadoCompartilhado
                                    .setArquivo(new File("C:\\Users\\Alunos\\Desktop\\ClienteUm\\ImagemQualquer.jpg")); // Caminho de onde será LIDO o arquivo para enviar
                            System.out.println("Arquivo enviado com sucesso!");
                        }

                        fluxoSaidaDados.writeObject(dadoCompartilhado);

                        fluxoSaidaDados.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private static void lerMensagemServidor() {
        new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        ObjectInputStream fluxoEntradaDados = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        DadoCompartilhado dadoCompatilhado = (DadoCompartilhado) fluxoEntradaDados.readObject();
                        System.out.println(dadoCompatilhado.getMensagem());

                        if (dadoCompatilhado.getArquivo() != null) {
                            InputStream entradaArquivo = null;
                            OutputStream saidaArquivo = null;

                            try {
                                entradaArquivo = new FileInputStream(dadoCompatilhado.getArquivo());
                                saidaArquivo = new FileOutputStream(
                                        new File("C:\\Users\\Alunos\\Desktop\\ClienteUm\\ImagemClienteUm.jpg")); // Caminho e nome que será gravado o Arquivo

                                byte[] memoriaTemporaria = new byte[1024 * 50];
                                int tamanho;
                                while ((tamanho = entradaArquivo.read(memoriaTemporaria)) > 0) {
                                    saidaArquivo.write(memoriaTemporaria, 0, tamanho);
                                }
                                System.out.println("Recebido com sucesso!");
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Maior que meus erros");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

### Cliente Dois

O mesmo serve para essa classe, que simula uma segunda aplicação conectada ao `Servidor Central` e com as mesmas funções que o `Cliente Um`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClienteDois {

    private static Socket socket;
    private static ObjectOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados;
    private static BufferedReader leitorBuffered;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.2", 12345);

            fluxoSaidaDados = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            leitorBuffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            escreverMensagemAoServidor(fluxoSaidaDados, leitorBuffered);
            lerMensagemServidor();

        } catch (IOException iec) {
            System.out.println(iec.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void lerMensagemServidor() {
        new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        ObjectInputStream fluxoEntradaDados = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        DadoCompartilhado dadoCompatilhado = (DadoCompartilhado) fluxoEntradaDados.readObject();
                        System.out.println(dadoCompatilhado.getMensagem());

                        if (dadoCompatilhado.getArquivo() != null) {
                            InputStream entradaArquivo = null;
                            OutputStream saidaArquivo = null;

                            try {
                                entradaArquivo = new FileInputStream(dadoCompatilhado.getArquivo());
                                saidaArquivo = new FileOutputStream(
                                        new File("C:\\Users\\Alunos\\Desktop\\ClienteDois\\ImagemClienteDois.jpg"));// Caminho e nome que será gravado o Arquivo

                                byte[] memoriaTemporaria = new byte[1024 * 50];
                                int tamanho;
                                while ((tamanho = entradaArquivo.read(memoriaTemporaria)) > 0) {
                                    saidaArquivo.write(memoriaTemporaria, 0, tamanho);
                                }
                                System.out.println("Recebido com sucesso!");
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Maior que meus erros");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private static void escreverMensagemAoServidor(final ObjectOutputStream fluxoSaidaDados,
            final BufferedReader leitorBuffered) throws IOException {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String mensagemSaida;
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        mensagemSaida = leitorBuffered.readLine();
                        DadoCompartilhado dadoCompartilhado = new DadoCompartilhado();
                        dadoCompartilhado.setEmailEntrega("127.0.0.3");
                        dadoCompartilhado.setMensagem("Mensagem do Cliente (2): " + mensagemSaida);
                        if (mensagemSaida.equals("Enviar")){
                            dadoCompartilhado
                                    .setArquivo(new File("C:\\Users\\Alunos\\Desktop\\ClienteDois\\ImagemQualquer.jpg")); // Caminho de onde será LIDO o arquivo para enviar
                            System.out.println("Arquivo enviado com sucesso!");
                        }

                        fluxoSaidaDados.writeObject(dadoCompartilhado);
                        fluxoSaidaDados.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

### INSTRUÇÕES

Não estão sendo feitos tratamentos de exceções corretamente, então para funcionar corretamente é preciso seguir os passos abaixo:

1. Execute o `Servidor Central`, ele precisa estar rodando para
   que haja a troca de mensagens
2. Execute qualquer um dos clientes, um ou dois, porém se inciar apenas um e enviar mensagem ao outro não iniciado, aparecerá um erro, que será resolvido somente se for iniciado o outro cliente.
3. Para enviar arquivos de um cliente ao outro é necessário antes de subi-los ao servidor, trocar os caminhos dos arquivos nos métodos, `lerMensagemServidor` e`escreverMensagemAoServidor` de cada uma das classes cliente e usar a palavra chave `Enviar` para acionar o método de envio de arquivos.